# Send data from main html page controller to a directive controller

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I was trying to communicate between controllers and directive. I have studied few blogs and searched stackoverflow, there are some wonderful concepts about these topics. But they all are case specific problems. I tried to solve my problem in their style but I found no luck.

My problem is.. I need to send some array to a directive. The array is defined in the controller of the main html file. And the html page has a directive too. Also the directive has his own controller to do some job. I need to send an array to that directive controller for processing and that array has to be two way binded so that any changes in one side can be reflected in another side.

Comment: Use an attribute when you call your directive

Comment: Can you post your code or any findings over internet?

Comment: I advice you reading this blog post .http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/

Comment: I tried to use factories and services. But  no results.

Comment: Thanks @katmanco, I will check it out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was dealing with this kind of situation lately and figured out a way to deal with it.
You can use this procedure to send data and process it in a directive from a controller.
First make a controller in the main page and define some array like you want...

```
app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.scope = $scope; //this is to transfer the current scope to the directive
    $scope.array = [{
        "a": "vfdxvf",
        "b": "sdc"
    }, {
        "a": "vfdxvf",
        "b": "sdc"
    }, {
        "a": "vfdxvf",
        "b": "sdc"
    }, {
        "a": "vfdxvf",
        "b": "sdc"
    }];
});
```

above in the code,  $scope.scope = $scope is to create reference of the controller scope.

And then define the directive like this. It will bind all the values you want. And Any change in the array on any side, will reflect on the other side as well.

Here is a dummy code..

```
app.directive("someDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        scope {
            array: "=", // two way binding of array..
            scope: '=' // collecting the scope of the controller it came from
        },
        templateUrl: "./templates/test.html",
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.newArray = $scope.scope.array;
            //do useful coding with the array... 
        }
    }
});
```

And for the html main page just write like this..

```
<some-directive scope="scope" array="array"></some-directive>
```

Answer (score 0):

use **=** in directive scope for bind controller variable

```
app.directive("myDir", function(){
  return{
    scope : {
      myArr : "="
    },
    controller : function($scope){

    },
    link : function(scope, ele, attr){
      scope.myArr.push("C");
    }
  }
});
```

see  https://plnkr.co/edit/pkkaEKBZVEajm5LBf9QD?p=preview